# Missing bytes when reading RS485 data using pySerial (Delta Solar Inverter)

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial, rs485

A solar inverter (Delta RPI M6A) has a master-slave RS485 bus.  The master asks the inverter a few times per second to send a response data set, which the inverter then does.  The total communication set is 176 bytes.
A Raspberry Pi 3B is connected to this bus using an FTDI FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC converter.

A Python program is used to read the data being transmitted on the bus.  This works fine only if there are no bytes that are interpreted as special characters (at least, that is what I think).
I first read the input 1 byte at a time.  Once the proper 'start of transmission' sequence has been found (STX followed by ACK followed by the inverterID=1) then the data set of 160 bytes plus an ending sequence is expected.  The last byte read should be ETX (= ascii 3).

The expected output is:
[Screenshot of expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1ULA.jpg)

I think the issue is that if some of the bytes are the equivalent of special characters like escape or linefeed, then those bytes are not 'seen' by the ser.read() command.  I will then get the ETX byte a few bytes sooner, indicating that some bytes somewhere in the middle were not captured.

The relevant portion of the code is:

```
if bytes_to_read == 1:
    raw_data = ser.read()
    pos = pos + 1;
    # print pos;
    if ord(raw_data) == 2:                                  # 2 = start of text character
        pos = 1;
        print str(pos) + ' ' + str(ord(raw_data))
    elif pos == 2 and ord(raw_data) == 6:                   # 6 = acknowledge character
        ack = True;
        print str(pos) + ' ' + str(ord(raw_data))
    elif pos == 2 and ord(raw_data) != 6:                   # 6 = acknowledge character
        ack = False;
        print str(pos) + ' ' + str(ord(raw_data)) + ' ack reset to False'
    elif pos == 3 and ack and ord(raw_data) == 1:
        bytes_to_read = 164;
        print str(pos) + ' ' + str(ord(raw_data))
elif bytes_to_read == 164:
    raw_data_byte = ser.read(164)
    print len(raw_data_byte);
    bytes_to_read = 1;
    ack = False;
    print 'got to read 164 bytes, first byte is ' + str(ord(raw_data_byte[0])) + ', last byte: ' + str(ord(raw_data_byte[163]));
    if ord(raw_data_byte[0]) == 160 and ord(raw_data_byte[163]) == 3:                     # 160 = data bytes specified by sender
        print ('ready to process ' + str(len(raw_data_byte)) + ' bytes')
        supplied_power_byte1 = bin(ord(raw_data_byte[101]))[2:].zfill(8)
        supplied_power_byte2 = bin(ord(raw_data_byte[102]))[2:].zfill(8)
```

The captured bytes are later processed to allow writing to a database.

I have been trying ser.read() and ser.readline(), with the same result.

I would be grateful for any hint that will point me in the right direction.

Thanks, 
Bram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set all special characters of the serial interface to 'undefined', using the cli command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stty -F /dev/RS-485 intr ^-
```

where '/dev/RS-485' is the symlink to a real USB port, and 'intr' is an example of the name of a special character.  When this is done for each special character (they can all be added to the above cli command), the port settings look like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stty -F /dev/RS-485 -g
1400:4:cbe:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

To see the settings in a more human-friendly format, use the command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stty -F /dev/RS-485 -a
```

All bytes now come in as expected.